# how to groupby multiple columns using python and pandas

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe that includes 4 columns my question is:
How to groupby 3 columns and plot the bar chart ?

How to plot the result of the groupby?

## code:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.offline
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objs as go

df =pd.DataFrame({"source_number":[11199,11328,11287,32345,12342,1232,13456,123244,1235],
       "location":["loc1","loc2","loc3","loc1","loc2","loc2","loc3","loc2","loc1"],
       "category":["cat1","cat3","cat1","cat3","cat3","cat2","cat2","cat3","cat1"],
       "date":["2021/04","2021/05","2021/04","2021/05","2021/05","2021/04","2021/03","2021/05","2021/04"]
                 }) 
# group by date with category and location  AND COUNT THE VALUES 
df_group = df.groupby(["date","category","location"]).size().reset_index(name="count")
df_group
```

Comment: What kind of bar chart? Separate bars for categories or locs or dates? 1 bar per row? There are lots of ways to make a bar chart from 4 columns of data.

Comment: bar chart based on date where the x axis is the date  and the bar chart will display the count of the combination between category and location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using:

```
df_group = (
    df.groupby(["date", "category", "location"])
        .size()
        .reset_index(name='count')
)
```

```
      date category location  count
0  2021/03     cat2     loc3      1
1  2021/04     cat1     loc1      2
2  2021/04     cat1     loc3      1
3  2021/04     cat2     loc2      1
4  2021/05     cat3     loc1      1
5  2021/05     cat3     loc2      3
```

Try creating a color indicator with `category` and `location`, plot, and drop:

```
import plotly.express as px

df_group['cat_location'] = df_group['category'] + '_' + df_group['location']
fig = px.bar(df_group, x="date", y="count", color='cat_location')
df_group = df_group.drop('cat_location', axis=1)
fig.show()
```

Or without adding a column to `df_group`:

```
fig = px.bar(df_group,
             x="date",
             y="count",
             color=df_group['category'] + '_' + df_group['location'])
fig.show()
```

[image: plotly plot]

Comment: how  to plot **df_group** using plotly and not matplotlib